# Java Servlet usage

Tags: java, servlets

I will have many Java Stand Alone applications running on multiple clients computer systems at “any given time”. These Java Stand Alone applications shall interface with my Resin 3.x Server to install the app on their HDD or to upload report data to a Server-Side DB...

Also, at “any given time”, an end user may interface with my Resin 3.x Server via a web page designed to purchase the application or a web page to dynamically view an application report...

My objective is to keep these Client-Server interface as simple as possible. So far, in my design, I have not used JSP or JPA or Java Beans...

I have specified a set of “Servlet commands” [17] designed to accomplish the above Client - Server interfaces. They are basically simple ‘Get’ and ‘Put’ commands to / from the 3 Server-Side DB’s...

I have designed 3 “Session” Servlets [DB_Servlet, Application_Servlet, HTML_Servlet] and allocated the 17 “Servlet Commands” accordingly...

The “Session” Servlets shall use the ‘Servlet.init’ method to establish an exclusive session. The exclusive session shall be destroyed once the App or HTML objectives are achieved...

BTW: I shall be using ‘Java EE 5’ and a ‘Resin 3.x Server’ to comply with requirements from the ISP that I may eventually employee to host my system...

In my attempt to “keep it simple” have I overlooked anything?

Comment: I'm having trouble pinpointing what you're actually trying to accomplish here.  I need to know that before I can suggest a simpler way.

Comment: I have 3 Database tables on my server that I need to manage from both Java Stand Alone apps and web pages [HTML]. Since I know Java, I thought the best way to do so is to write Java Servlets. My query goal is to assure myself that I have not over-simplified the effort by just using Servlets.I have read many servlet related items on StackOverflow and elsewhere that reference JPA, Enterprise Java Beens, etc. I think I can just use Java Servlets but I placed this query to see if I have overlooked anything in my deign...

Comment: Have you done servlets and jsp before on other projects?

Comment: @developerwjk No, these will be my first. I think of them as just another Java class that is a Server-Side object waiting to perform a service. To me, so far, the session is like a container so no Java Bean [or whatever else] is required. Since all my servlet commands shall interface with Server-Side DB's perhaps I do need JPA to assure that my servlet command has completed. I was hoping that my initial description was sufficient enough to obtain some suggestions, perhaps not. Regards...